# String Panda series to string variable

Tags: python, pandas

Have been looking for the way to get a String variable from a string column in dataframe. In the most basic scenario, I have a String variable called name which is spplitted based on space to get a string list (in the example called names). Then, the list is sent as parameter to the function to process each element of the list:

```
name = "4 PAWS ONLY"
type(name) #String type
names= name.split()
type(names) #list type
print(names) #['4', 'PAWS', 'ONLY']

#avg_vector needs a list of string, called names
avg_vector = avg_sentence_vector(names, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist()
```

In this basic scenario, avg_sentence_vector executes with no error because the arguments satisfy the function input.

In the ideal scenario, the same logic applies, but for each row of a dataframe. The strings are are comming from the column called "name" (instead of a string variable)which will need to get spplitted in the same way as previous example and pass a list to the function.

So far, I have not been able to get a list of strings after splitting the String value from "name" column:

```
names = ['4 PAWS ONLY']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=range(1), columns=['names', 'avg_vector'])
df['names'] = names

vname = df.names.apply(str)
type(vname) #pandas.core.series.Series

vnames = vname.str.split()
type(vnames) #pandas.core.series.Series

print(vname)
0    [4, PAWS, ONLY]
Name: names, dtype: object

#avg_vector needs a list of string, called vnames
avg_vector = avg_sentence_vector(vnames, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist()
```

The execution of the function shows the following error:

```
<ipython-input-9-2abbbce044f5> in avg_sentence_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set)
---> 11         if word in index2word_set:
     12             nwords = nwords+1
     13             featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The body of the function `avg_sentence_vector` is as follows:

```
##Get average sentence vector

def avg_sentence_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set):
    #function to average all words vectors in a given paragraph
    featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
    nwords = 0

    for word in words:
        print(word)
        print(index2word_set)
        if word in index2word_set:
            nwords = nwords+1
            featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])

    if nwords>0:
        featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
    return featureVec
```

How can I pass a list of string from a dataframe String column? Is there another possible cause of the failure?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure I have understood: do you want to apply the `avg_sentence_vector` function to each element of column `names` and store the result in column `avg_vector`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Valentino, yes, I need to invoke the avg_sentence_vector function to each element of column names and store in the column avg_vector. In the example, avg_vector is just a variable, but it is another column in the dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in the following way:

```
def avg_sentence_vector(ll, *args, **kwargs):
    return len(ll)

df['avg_vector'] = df.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row['names'].split()), axis=1)
```

This returns:

```
         names  avg_vector
0  4 PAWS ONLY           3
```

As you see, in my case the `avg_sentence_vector` function returns the length of the passed list, but of course it can be anything. You can pass all the extra arguments you want too.

#### EDIT after comments

Be careful to not mix the arguments of your function with `apply` arguments, like `axis`. If your function takes more than one argument, you need to do:

```
df['avg_vector'] = df.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row['names'].split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, ...), axis=1)
```

where `...` stands for any other argument your function may require. All of them need to be inside the parenthesis of `avg_sentence_vector`, and axis=1 must be the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Valentino, I see that your example works very well when printing `df` dataframe, but when applying to my code as follows: `----> 7 df['avg_vector'] = df.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row['names'].split(), axis=1, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist())` I am getting the following error: `KeyError: ('names', 'occurred at index names')`, even though the axis=1 is included.

Comment: you are mixing the arguments of your function with the arguments of `apply`. I've edited my answer, check it.

Comment: This make sense on this [panda documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), I realized the axis=1 (apply function to each row in the column) should be at the end (as you already mentioned), so I edited as `7 df['avg_vector'] = df.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row['names'].split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist(), axis=1)`  and getting a new error: `AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'tolist'", 'occurred at index 0')`. Srry if undrstandg s inadquat

Comment: The extra `)` is there because to list is using the result of avg_sentence_vector as follows:
`df['avg_vector'] = df.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row...,index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist())` where the n-1 `)` is closing `set` and the last `)` is closing `avg_sentence_vector`.

Comment: Seems that your function is not returning a numpy array as expected then, only an integer. Check the return value of your function.